# iPad application - how to kill server call using finger swipe

Tags: ios, multithreading, ipad, uiscrollview, lazy-loading

We are building a image catalog iPad application. We are using 2 types of images: low res thumbnails (250 * 500 pixels) and high res full images (2048X2048 pixels). The high res image sizes are 200kb to 10mb each. We have implemented lazy loading and multithreading for downloads of high res images.

As its a image catalog application, total images can be between 200 to 500 images. This application has offline support so we are storing images in application document directory to show all downloaded images later. There is feature for alphabetical sorting of images so we have to show all low resolution images on screen at same time through UIScrollView.

When a new high res image is invoked, the image mostly take between 3-8 seconds every time an image is opened for the first time. This pretty much freezes the app and the user has to wait 3-8 seconds before he can do anything else.

My developer has pretty much said that there is no easy way to allow user to stop current action and move to next image until the full current image is download to memory.

Experts do you think we should be able to implement the code in a way that when high res images are being downloaded, any user action will super cede the current high res image download. E.g. finger swipe will enable header bar (contains back button, settings button) and take user to next image?

Thanks for your prompt reply guys. But as we have mentioned in our questions we have used Lazy loading/ Multithreading that means we have used NSURLConnection Asynchronous request. We are not using main thread for downloading even not for text data.

We have created a Image downloader class with NSURLConnection and delegates. We have written our custom protocol to send notifications to corresponding controllers after success/fail of each image's request.

```
@protocol TImageDownloaderDelegate

-(void)imageDownloadedSuccessfully:(ImageDownloader *)inDownloader;
-(void)prImageDownloadedSuccessfully :(ImageDownloader *)inDownloader;

@end
```

The issue is, we have multiple ( more than 160 )  images in same screen using UIScrollView, and for each images we have high resolution images (size between 200KB to 10 MB) and we are downloading high res images and just after downloading each images we are refreshing view. So sometimes scroll is not very smooth while rendering view again and again. So we are looking for some way to improve the performance of application.

Comment: The app should be responsive at every time

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely a way to do this (in fact, there may be several ways). My preferred way is to use an [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instance to manage the download of your larger image - you can create the connection to an image, then cancel it later if the user requests it or if you need to move to another image.

What's more, your application *should not* be freezing as you download images. You need to have your developer place those downloads on a background thread, so that they won't interfere with the proper performance of your user interface. If your application is nonresponsive due to network connections for long enough, it may even be terminated by the operating system. There are a number of guides online for backgrounding NSURLConnection instances or threading in general on iOS - I strongly recommend you follow one of them.

**Edit:** With additional info provided by AmitS, I would also say to work on your lazy rerendering of the view in question. You might consider batching up downloads and only rerendering when all the images in the user's visible area are downloaded, or not rendering 160+ high-resolution images on one screen - at that size, thumbnails might suffice, and you can put off rendering the high-res image until the user zooms in on it or selects it to fill the screen. Think carefully about whether you actually need 160 high-res images all rendered on the same view; the performance hit you take in rendering so many images could negate any user benefit to having the images high-res in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in principle, although the app may not immediately respond to the cancellation gesture or tap. You can use `NSOperation`, and cancel a long-running action as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) (search for "Responding to the Cancel Command").

Also, as @Tim has said in his answer, your app should NOT freeze while a large image is being loaded. If that happens, it means that the image downloading is implemented wrong (it probably does it on the main thread, which is a fundamental mistake).